# Enable Python code only for unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def f():
    if TESTING:
        # Run expensive sanity check code
    ...
```

What is the correct way to run the TESTING code block only if we are running a unittest?

[edit: Is there some "global" variable I can access to find out if unittests are on?]

Comment: Can't you just put the expensive sanity-check code directly in your unittest?

Comment: No because the unittest calls some common code, and that common code has expensive code paths that I want to check. Also, there are functions that I want to check produce the same output if I shuffle intermediary values, but I don't want to shuffle intermediary values in production code.

Comment: You need to re-factor the functions so you can mock / patch out the code you don't want to run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, I'd suggest not doing this.  Your production-code really shouldn't realize that the unit-tests exist.  One reason for this, is that you could have code in your `if TESTING` block that makes the tests pass (accidentally), and since production runs of your code won't run these bits, could leave you exposed to failure in production even when your tests pass.

*However*, if you insist of doing this, there are two potential ways (that I can think of) this can be done.

First of, you could use a module level `TESTING` var that you set in your test case to `True`.  For example:

**Production Code:**

```
TESTING = False    # This is false until overridden in tests

def foo():
    if TESTING:
        print "expensive stuff..."
```

**Unit-Test Code:**

```
import production

def test_foo():
    production.TESTING = True
    production.foo()    # Prints "expensive stuff..."
```

The second way is to use python's builtin `assert` keyword.  When python is run with `-O`, the interpreter will strip (or ignore) all assert statements in your code, allowing you to sprinkle these expensive gems throughout and know they will not be run if it is executed in optimized mode.  Just be sure to run your tests without the `-O` flag.

**Example (Production Code):**

```
def expensive_checks():
    print "expensive stuff..."
    return True

def foo():
    print "normal, speedy stuff."
    assert expensive_checks()

foo()
```

**Output (run with `python mycode.py`)**

```
normal, speedy stuff.
expensive stuff...
```

**Output (run with `python -O mycode.py`)**

```
normal, speedy stuff.
```

One word of caution about the assert statements... if the assert statement does not evaluate to a true value, an `AssertionError` will be raised.

Comment: +1 but really don't do that. 'tis better to have `foo.expensive_test_to_ensure_some_invariant()` which is called by the test rig than to have code that changes depending on the calling environment. Better explicit than implicit, as they say.

Comment: @msw I agree.  I think I sprinkled enough warnings throughout my answer.  I can add more if need be.

Comment: I was really just adding amplification to your copious warnings. Bitter experience has shown me that "If you must" can always be answered "of course I do" even if false.

Comment: I will heed your advice if you can explain further why I shouldn't, because I don't understand. " is that you could have code in your if TESTING block that makes the tests pass (accidentally), and since production runs of your code won't run these bits" But if I copy-and-paste the test code, then these tests will pass anyhow. So what's the difference?

Comment: Also, what about when "if TESTING" blocks just do extra asserts and sanity checks? What is wrong with those? Why should I refactor them out? (And how, if they're deep in a function?) Why aren't these sufficiently explicit?